# C++ data structures: converting from TNT Vector to GL vec3

Tags: c++, data-structures, iterator

I'm using a data structure not written by myself that returns a realVec. This is the declaration of realVec (in typedef.h):

```
typedef TNT::Vector<PCReal> realVec;
```

For the definition of TNT Vector please see: http://calicam.sourceforge.net/doxygen/tnt__vector_8h_source.html

Definition of PCReal:

```
typedef double PCReal;
```

I need to convert this realVec into the following vec3:

```
struct vec3 {

GLfloat  x;
GLfloat  y;
GLfloat  z;

//
//  --- Constructors and Destructors ---
//

vec3( GLfloat s = GLfloat(0.0) ) :
x(s), y(s), z(s) {}

vec3( GLfloat _x, GLfloat _y, GLfloat _z ) :
x(_x), y(_y), z(_z) {}

vec3( const vec3& v ) { x = v.x;  y = v.y;  z = v.z; }

vec3( const vec2& v, const float f ) { x = v.x;  y = v.y;  z = f; }
...
```

I'm very new to C++ so my confusion probably lies in using TNT::Vector's iterator and converting values returned by it. I'm thinking something like the below, so tell me if it makes sense. It seems to compile (no 'make' errors):

```
realVec normal = this->meshPoints.getNormalForVertex(i);
PCReal* iter = normal.begin();

vec3(*iter++, *iter++, *iter++);
```

I need this because I'm doing gl programming, and it's convenient for my shaders to take vec3's as input.

Comment: I edited above. Looks like a double.

Comment: If a PCReal is a double, how do you want that converted to a struct with 3 floats? Do you want to call the first vec3 constructor with a PCReal?

Comment: @BrianNeal Since the Vector is of type PCReal, vectors in general naturally contain multiple values, so Vector will hopefully contain 3 PCReals. In that case I'd want to use the second constructor, inserting the 3 PCReals (see my proposed code block, the last block in my question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have might work, but you could improve it with some safety checks, and you don't really have to use iterators at all. It appears realVec provides `operator[]` like most other vector classes.

```
realVec normal = this->meshPoints.getNormalForVertex(i);
if (normal.size() >= 3)
{
   vec3 x(normal[0], normal[1], normal[2]);
}
```

Comment: See my response to your comment above. I'll try my code first, unless someone can show it's wrong. Then I'll consider yours, thanks.

Comment: Rewrote my answer based on your comment above.

Comment: Ah so I should be able to access realVec components using array syntax rather than using the iterator. Looks like it compiles. That's my answer for now, I may come back if I get runtime errors.